# mysql gem install error in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby, macos, installation, rubygems

I just got put in charge of a new app, one that is already built, to add new features and the like to it.  Unfortunately, It was built several years ago (using rails 2.1) and uses mysql (I prefer postgres).  I am attempting to install the mysql gem so I can mess about with the code on my local machine and I am getting the following error.

```
$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/opt/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... no
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/opt/local/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config


Gem files will remain installed in /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

I checked the directory /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config to make sure the file existed (it does)...I installed mysql with the dmg file (v 5.1) from the mysql site.

Frankly I'm at a loss as for how the hell to fix this.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Check if mysql.h actually exists on your machine. It should be in /usr/local/mysql/include. If it's not there, can you please post the output of running /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the mysql header files are included in the dmg-file. Install either Homebrew or Macports and run `brew install mysql` or `sudo port -v install mysql5-server mysql5`